# get the url of link from href='javascript:somefunction()'

Tags: javascript, junit, anchor, htmlunit

Some websites uses following code for href field in anchor tag:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('DataGrid1$ctl03$ctl00','')">LINK< /a>
```

The _doPostBack function is defined as

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Now if I want to get the url of that link,what should I do? I do not know the path of the file in the directory.

I found out that htmlUnit can be used for this purpose. Can any one tell me how to use htmlUnit here? I haven't ever used it,so I don't know how it actually works.

Comment: Such links are generated by asp.net and initiate a "post" request, usually with parameters; their URL alone is probably insufficient for generating the desired output.

Comment: I intend to download the webpage with several anchor tags like this.So how can I reach the desired page then??